# Как подключить css и js в битрикс?

Tags: битрикс

На локальном сервере(Open Server) сайт выглядит так как нужно, но когда я подключаю html шаблон к bitrix(через WinSCP), то все стили пропадают.

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 0):

А как Вы сейчас подключаете? Можете дать ссылку на сайт чтобы посмотреть ?

Вообще вот так:

```php
use Bitrix\Main\Page\Asset;

Asset::getInstance()->addJs(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH . "/js/fix.js"); 
Asset::getInstance()->addCss(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH . "/styles/fix.css"); 
Asset::getInstance()->addString("<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400&subset=cyrillic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>");
```

Прописывается в header или footer шаблона.